# How to detect SQL Injection sitting at a reverse proxy?

Tags: security, sql-injection, reverse-proxy

I am writing a simple `reverse proxy` in java. So, I have access to all `Http requests and responses` exchanged between client and server. Sitting at the proxy I am trying to detect SQL Injection Attack.

I got few links - (like for example)

http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/detection-sql-injection-and-cross-site-scripting-attacks

where some regex are mentioned, but I suppose it's not that simple. 
It is impossible to write regex for all possible/valid SQL statements.
Because so many databases are there in the market and SQL statements must follow some grammer rules.

Let me break down the problem to a simple question -

`Given a string, can it be checked that whether it contains a valid SQL statement?`

Can anyone tell me the best way to do it? Or, any library which does that for me?

Comment: A sql injection attack is valid sql. That's why it works

Comment: But it's too late to know if your database server has some vulnerability.

Answer (score 2):

Let me first take my hat off to @neil-mcguigan who came up with the best comment of the year: "A sql injection attack is valid sql. That's why it works"

While keeping that axiom in mind, I think it's possible to rely on some heuristics to identify and block malicious behavior in general. For example, you will often see multiple unsuccessful attempts during an attack. The attacker's behavior and various attributes (such as source geo-IP, access time, user-agent or browser thumbprint, etc.) will likely be different from the average regular user. Many network security appliances in the market actually use these and combine them with other threat feeds for detection.

However, as soon as you grow to more than a single server to protect, it becomes extremely hard to *persist* and leverage this information. In a web farm, with load balancers and multiple reverse proxies, getting access to logs from every device, in real-time, and running heuristics against every unknown call is a bigger challenge than coming up with the heuristics themselves.

Comment: What if a regular/legitimate user tries to hack using SQL Injection?

Comment: Then I would posit that it's not the reverse proxy's role to detect that. In any case it's the underlying app's responsibility to use secure coding practices and not yield to known bad behavior.

Comment: AWS WAF does that: https://aws.amazon.com/waf/ but yes it needs some predefined rules.

Comment: Agreed. IMHO, as the industry moves more towards [Software-defined Networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_networking), I think we're seeing more of these type of services take over what would normally be provided at the [edge router](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_device) level. I'm sure as we speak, AWS developers are working on features to make WAF more intelligent with more built-in rules.